# Combined Buy/Restore button for non-consumable IAP in iOS?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store, design-guidelines

My question is not about the programming part, but the UI best-practices for IAP.

Situation: I have a single IAP ("Unlimited version") for my app, where I have a "Purchase" button, which will show inactive and change the text to "Activated" when purchased.
In case of a reinstall, the "Purchase" button would restore directly, which got my app rejected because of "Guideline 3.1.1 - Business - Payments - In-App Purchase" which says in the end, that automatic restores do not comply and a "Restore" button needs to be displayed.

So I added a check for previous purchases when entering the Settings page which is showing the "Purchase" button which will then change the button text from "Purchase" to "Restore". However, this is not instantly (depending on the connection), so this version also got rejected.

Objective: For a seamelss user experience, I didn't want to show both "Purchase" and "Restore" buttons next to each other for a single IAP line. On the other hand, if checking for previous purchases right at app startup, this could raise a AppStore login request (then unrelated to user action), which would also be awkward.

Question: does anyone have experience whether a button showing "Buy / Restore" would be accepted by AppStore Review? Or how do you usually position Restore button? I understand that, for apps with multiple IAPs it makes sense, to have ONE Restore button, but in my case it doesn't look right, because the user must know/decide whether he already purchased the IAP or not (which is completely unnecessary).

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Just show both buttons. The user probably knows when they need to restore (new/additional/erased device) and will tap restore. They will also understand why the purchase button is shown (again, new/additional/erased device). If they do tap purchase there is no harm since the purchase will be processed as a restore and they won't be charged.

Comment: Yes, it got approved now with both buttons, but I still think it's not a good user experience. I'd rather check whether it would be a first Buy or a Restore and only show the corresponding button.... but well... the rules are the rules :-)